# I want to show one norm is less than or equal to another norm on C([0,1])

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $|| \ ||_1$ be the norm on $C([0,1])$ defined by $||f||_1 = \int_0^1|f(t)|dt$.

a) Show that $||f||_1 \le ||f||_{[0,1]}$

b) Are $|| \ ||_1$ and $|| \ ||_{[0,1]}$ equivalent?

For part a) I think this works, but any help would be great if there are glaring problems

$\int_0^1|f(t)| dt\le \int_0^1\max_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|dt=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|=||f||_{[0,1]}$

And for part b) I am thinking its wrong (or they would have said prove it) so do I just need to find a function where the two norms give different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** consider a piecewise function $f_n$,
taking the value $n$ in $0$, affine on $(0,1/n^2)$, and taking the value $0$ from $1/n^2$ to $1$.

$\|f_n\|_1 = 1/2n, \|f\|_{[0,1]} = n$.

Comment: how is part a)  ?

Comment: it looks great.

Comment: how did you find $||f_n||_1$ ?

Comment: this is the area of the triangle with coins $(0,n), (0,0), (1/n^2, 0)$ that is $1/2*n*1/n^2$

Comment: would it not be $int_0^0ndx+\int_0^{\frac{1}{n^2}}xdx+\int_{\frac{1}{n^2}}^10dx$?

Comment: no. between $0$ and $1/n^2$ the function is $n - n^3 x$ (that is why it has the value $n$ in 0 and $0$ in $1/n^2$)

Comment: wow how did you figure that out so quick? What was your thinking?

Comment: Also, thanks....

Comment: you want a function that has a little average but  takes big values. You can try with functions that takes high values on very little intervals!